# How to use FunctionTransformer with a custom function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I want to use FunctionTransformer to perform calculations between columns. For instance, I want to substract two columns and add the the new column to the dataset. So I have the function:

```
def diff(x, y):
    return x - y
```

my initial dataset is:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({"product":["a","b","c","d"], "ndp":[100,200,150,120], "discount":[5,10,15,30]})

  product  ndp  discount
0       a  100         5
1       b  200        10
2       c  150        15
3       d  120        30
```

and I need a new column price = ndp - discount, so I run:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

transf = FunctionTransformer(diff, kw_args={'x': 'ndp', 'y':"discount"})
func_transf.transform(X)
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: diff() got multiple values for argument 'x'
```

How can I pass the arguments to the function diff and how to specify the name of the new column?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `FunctionTransformer`, like most scikit-learn classes, is designed to work with NumPy arrays, rather than whole dataframes. So your function should also take in and return a NumPy array.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def diff(X: np.array) -> np.array:
    d = (X[:, 0] - X[:, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)
    return np.concatenate((X, d), axis=1)

X = pd.DataFrame({"product": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], 
                  "ndp": [100, 200, 150, 120], 
                  "discount": [5, 10, 15, 30]})

transf = FunctionTransformer(diff) 
X_new = transf.transform(X[['ndp', 'discount']].values)

print(X_new)
```

```
[[100   5  95]
 [200  10 190]
 [150  15 135]
 [120  30  90]]
```